# Include file while passing GET Values in while loading?

Tags: php, include

I have a file which i created that requires you to pass in a specific key in order to load the full page, otherwise it will give you an error.

That all works great but i have another page where if you submit the form it will include the file which requires GET values, how do i go about doing this?

I tried:

```
include 'schedulechecker.php?key=1233key';
```

Comment: do you have a class with a method in schedulechecker.php ? 
If not, I would suggest putting the script in a method. That way you can include the file, initiate the class and then send your key to the method, returning true (key is correct) or false (key is incorrect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using GET values in include is not possible include does't use an http request it just gets the contents of the file and includes it in

you can use a variable and pass using it

```
$key = '123key';
include 'schedulechecker.php';
```

if you want to use get values for that file as well

just use another variable in shedulechecker.php and assign the value after checking if `$_GET['key']` exist

```
if(isset($_GET['key'])&& $_GET['key']!=""){
    $key =$_GET['key'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not pssible to pass your parameter using `GET` with `include` You can do something like below.

```
$key = '123key';
include 'schedulechecker.php';
```

Now you can use `$key` in your `schedulechecker.php` file.